# Login 2.0 Django, autenticação

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando fazer uma página de login, mas estou tendo algumas dificuldades. Por alguma razão que eu não consigo entender, toda vez que digito o usuário e a senha, seja certo ou não, dá a resposta que o usuário não existe.

Meu bando de dados é o **SQL Server 2017**.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Person
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Person(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('Authenticated sucessfully')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Disable account')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid Login')
else:
    form = Person()
    return render(request, 'login2.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Loginteste

class Person(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Loginteste
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Loginteste(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'loginteste'
```

**login2.html**

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="." method="post" class="form-signin">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </form>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: por que você usa dois `forms` aninhados?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o problema esteja em que seu modelo `Loginteste` não herda das classes bases do Django.

Se o se interesse é ter um modelo personalisado para os seu usuários, eu sugiro consultar a documentação sobre "[Definindo um modelo de usuário personalizado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)" em português.

Então você poderia fazer algo como (adaptado do exemplo da documentação):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
class Loginteste(AbstractBaseUser):
    identificador = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'identificador'
```

Uma alternativa, também documentada, é com "[Estendendo o modelo Usuário existente](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)" - também em português.

Bem, isso foi o que entendi a partir do que seu código faz. Espero que seja útil.